# How to get correct resolution of variadic template function without being too verbose

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

My question is about a compilation error I was getting when defining and using a variadic function. I will give a minimal example below.

First I defined a function to print an object:
(all code is [here](https://ideone.com/SwhUPd))

```
template <typename T>
void print(T t){
    std::cout << t<<std::endl;
}
```

Next, I defined a function that will allow you to transform an object and then print it:

```
template <typename T>
void print(T t,std::function<void(T& t)> transformer){
    transformer(t);
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

Next, I wanted to define a function that will let you call either of the two above functions, but will result in printing a label and the result. I can achieve this with a variadic function template:

```
template <typename... Params>
void printLabeled(std::string label,Params... params){
    std::cout << label << ": ";
    print(params...);
}
```

Now I can try to use the code. The main thing I want to do is call `printLabeled("answer",1,{[](int& num){num+=1;}});`, but this doesn't work. I have to do something more verbose. Is there any way to do the function call without be more verbose than `printLabeled("answer",1,{[](int& num){num+=1;}});`? Again, you can run the code [here](https://ideone.com/SwhUPd). Examples of function calls that work and don't work are below.

```
int main() {
    //prints the number '1', as expected
    print(1);

    //prints the number the label "answer" and then the number one
    printLabeled("answer",1);

    //I intended this to increment 1 to 2 and then print 2,
    //but I guess the lambda does not get converted to an std::function,
    //so this doesn't work
    //print(1,[](int& num){num+=1;});

    //This does was the above line was intended to do
    print(1,{[](int& num){num+=1;}});

    //I intended this to be the labeled version of the above line,
    //but for some reason, this doesn't work anymore
    // printLabeled("answer",1,{[](int& num){num+=1;}});

    //This labeled version does work finally,
    //but its pretty verbose
    printLabeled("answer",1,std::function<void(int&)>([](int& num){num+=1;}));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename F>
void print(T t, F transformer){
    transformer(t);
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print(T t){
    std::cout << t<<std::endl;
}

template <typename... Params>
void printLabeled(std::string label, Params&&... params){
    std::cout << label << ": ";
    print(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}

int main() {
    //prints the number '1', as expected
    print(1);

    //prints the number the label "answer" and then the number one
    printLabeled("answer",1);

    //This does was the above line was intended to do
    print(1, [](int& num){num+=1;});

    //I intended this to be the labeled version of the above line,
    //but for some reason, this doesn't work anymore
    printLabeled("answer", 1, [](int& num){num+=1;});

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/JTYUpa

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to keep the same type safety I was originally going for, (I can only pass in an std::function<void(T&)>), should that be done by using std::enable_if?